# Understanding Promise.fromCallback

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I was reading an article [Promises](https://runnable.com/blog/bluebird-in-the-wild-advanced-promise-based)
I came across `Promise.fromCallBack`. I went through the article but was not able to fully understand it.

Can anyone explain what Promise.fromCallBack does and when to use it?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Can anyone explain what `Promise.fromCallBack` does and when to use it.

Comment: Documentation is pretty clear. This Bluebird static method provides an alternative approach to promisification in cases where `.promisify()`/`.promisifyAll()` don't work. The syntax is slightly cumbersome which is why `.fromCallback()` wouldn't be your first choice on most occasions.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

[Promise.fromCallBack returns a promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.fromcallback.html). This is used if you want to wrap a function in a promise on the fly.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const User = require('./models/user')

return Promise.fromCallback((cb) => {
  User.findById(ID, cb)
})
  .then(user => console.log(user))
```

is basically

```
 const Promise = require('bluebird')
 const User = require('./models/user')

 return // the result of User.findById(ID) in a resolver function 
  .then(user => console.log(user))
```

**Longer version:**

Based on [the original blog](https://runnable.com/blog/bluebird-in-the-wild-advanced-promise-based), 
`Promise.fromCallback` is an alternative to use `Promise((resolve, reject))`

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  User.findById(ID, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
    return resolve(user)
  })
})
  .then(user => console.log(user))
```

Based on the [bluebird description of `new Promise`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html), the above code creates a promise for `User.findById(ID, callback)`, except wrapping it in a resolver function `(resolve, reject) => {}`.

`User.findById(ID, resultCallback)` means:

```
User.findById(ID).then((user) => {...}).catch((err) => {})
```

The `.then` part is created by `resolve()`, and the `.catch` part is create by `reject()`. Now the resolver basically creates the `reject` and `resolve` function.

From the blog, we can see that `promise.fromCallback` pass in a callback function instead of manually create a resolver function.

```
return Promise.fromCallback((cb) => {
  User.findById(ID, cb)
})
  .then(user => console.log(user))
```

This basically wraps the result from the callback in a promise and resolve/ reject it.

Answer (score -3):

Callback functions are derived from a programming paradigm known as functional programming. At a fundamental level, functional programming specifies the use of functions as arguments.

A callback function, also known as a higher-order function, is a function that is passed to another function (let’s call this other function “otherFunction”) as a parameter, and the callback function is called (or executed) inside the otherFunction. A callback function is essentially a pattern (an established solution to a common problem), and therefore, the use of a callback function is also known as a callback pattern.

```js
let promise = doSomething(); 
promise.then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

[Read More:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Sorry, but every single sentence in this answer is mistaken. (And also doesn't answer the question at all)